Figure and Table Arrangement in Proof Correction for Accepted Article
I received the proof of my accepted article in the Electrical Engineering journal (one of Springer’s journals) yesterday, and they requested that I send the corrected proof within two days.
I am currently preparing the annotated PDF proof. However, I have a question regarding the arrangement of figures and tables. In the proof I received, they are not placed in the locations I specified in my last submission. Additionally, some of the tables are not formatted as I originally designed them.
Could you please advise on how I should annotate or correct these issues in the proof?

Reach out to the editorial staff handling proofs, explain exactly what you want (and politely enquire if that is doable for that journal, they may have some strict formatting conventions they are asked for follow for whatever reason), and firmly but politely request that you wish to see the proofs again before signing off on them. The two day thing is a polite suggestion, you can take longer if needed (that is done to manage workflow and to keep the submission to acceptance to publication times for the journal low). Your focus is that your work should be represented as you intend.

@R1NaNo, that should probably be an answer.
